# How to list each drive and usage in Linux

Tags: php, linux

I want to list each physical drive attached to the machine and then display free/used space. I've used.

```
fdisk -l | grep '^Disk'
```

to get a list drives and their capacity. But I want it to show spaced used too. I'd like this not be non interactive too as I'm using a php script to get the information.

are there any other commands that can get the info?

Comment: Physical drives and filesystems are two **very** different things. Free space on physical drives doesn't mean what you think it means (it is almost always zero or near zero). It usually makes sense to check free/used space information on filesystems, not drives. `df -h` will give you that, for those which are mounted by the system.

Comment: What do you mean by free/used space? Do you mean space taken by partitions and unclaimed space, or free/used space on those partitions?

Comment: I basically want to give a system overview including disk usage. But rather than filesystem space, I was thinking actual disk usage. maybe I should rethink my approach?

Answer (score 4):

Just try with:

```
df -h
```

It should give you what you want.

```
-h, --human-readable  print sizes in human readable format (e.g., 1K 234M 2G)
```

Answer (score 0):

`df -BM` (`-BM` signifies that you want the information in megabytes)

Answer (score 0):

The df command can do this:

```
main% df -h
Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/vg_new-lv_root
                  359G  226G  115G  67% /
tmpfs                 4.0G  2.3M  4.0G   1% /dev/shm
/dev/sdf1             464M   49M  391M  12% /boot
```